# Check if column was logged before another column in the same day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two columns, a user id column, and time logs, I want to find out how many of them occur after one another.

One column is the name of the event, other column is a numerical value. Each input has a timestamp and an identifier user id. Event and value columns are logged independently, so never in the same row. value is logged once per day per user. I want to know how many of the values are logged before an event log in the same day.

Data looks like:

```
df
timestamp           id   value   event
2020-10-10 13:21    4      12     NaN
2020-10-10 15:10    4      NaN    Walk
2020-10-10 10:14    7      NaN    Read
2020-10-10 12:53    7       89     NaN
....
```

So looking at each id, check if value data was logged before an event log in the same day.

Also, I want to find out have many of the events were logged within 10-minutes of a value log.
How can I achieve these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

> I want to know how many of the values are logged before an event log in the same day

```
# Create a date column
df1 = df.assign(date=df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()).set_index(['id', 'date'])

# Value rows
m = df1['value'].notna()

# Diff and count
diff = df1.loc[m, 'timestamp'] - df1.loc[~m, 'timestamp']
count = (diff.gt('0D').map({True: 'Events after value', False: 'Events before value'})
             .value_counts())
print(count)

# Output
Events after value     1
Events before value    1
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

> I want to find out have many of the events were logged within 10-minutes of a value log

```
count10m = sum(('0' <= diff) & (diff <= '10m'))
print(count10m)

# Output
0
```